# Encoding for arabic website

Tags: php, html

i just want to know the difference between utf-8 and windows-1256 encoding.I am building arabic website which encoding is better to use.

Answer (score 2):

utf-8 includes a wide range of characters (not only Arabic characters), while windows-1256 is an Arabic code page. I prefer utf-8 as not all computers install windows-1256 by default.

Answer (score 0):

You could have [Googled](https://www.google.nl/search?q=windows%201256) it. In short. Windows-1256 is a code page (meaning in this case only 8 bit characters are in there), UTF-8 encodes (almost) all characters out there.

Use UTF-8 if you have the choice.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 can represent all supported character sets at once, while Windows-1256 can only support arabic + some latin characters needed mostly for french.

I'd go for UTF-8, just in case you want to use any non arabic characters in your site later.